# How to properly split the rent/utilities

Tags: rental-property

I'm confused on the order I'm supposed to calculate all of these values between me and my roommate.

**Rent agreement:** We split the rent, utilities and internet but I pay `$30` extra for the bigger room and `$50` for the storage unit.

```
+----------+-----------+
| Rent     | $1,505.00 |
+----------+-----------+
| Util     | $139.36   |
+----------+-----------+
| Internet | $91       |
+----------+-----------+
| Storage  | $50       |
+----------+-----------+
| Total    | $1,785.36 |
+----------+-----------+
```

So would I sum the `Rent`+`Util`+`Internet`, subtract the $30 and then divide it to find what my roommate owes?

Comment: Why not split the rent 52/48 instead? At the current rate, it works out the same, and it scales with any future increases in your monthly rent?

Answer (score 1):

```
($1,785.36 - $30)/2 * 2 + $30 = $1,785.36
```

Thus, yes: that's exactly what I'd do.

EDIT: after your edit, it's probably easier to divvy up each line item instead of lumping it all together and then adjusting.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm confused on the order I'm supposed to calculate all of these values between me and my roommate.

So long as you subtract the $30 from the rent before you divide by two, it's fine.

> So would I sum the `Rent`+`Util`+`Internet`, subtract the $30 and then divide it to find what my roommate owes?

That order would work, but I'd probably divide up the rent first instead.  Unlike utilities, the rent will be the same each month.  So you can do

```
(1505 - 30) / 2 + 50 + 30 = 817.50
```

That's your share, and your roommate owes

```
(1505 - 30) / 2 = 737.50
```

That should stay the same.  For this month, you also have

```
(139.36 + 91) / 2 = 115.18
```

So you have

```
817.50 + 115.18 = 932.68
```

and your roommate owes

```
737.50 + 115.18 = 852.68
```

For a total of

```
932.68 + 852.68 = 1785.36
```

Where you pay 80 more than your roommate.

The point of working out the monthly rent first is that it leaves less math to make mistakes.  You might be able to roll the internet into that as well.  Not sure if the 91 is always the same or not.

---

If he pays for the internet, it's even simpler.

```
139.36 / 2 = 69.68
```

So you owe

```
817.50 + 69.68 = 887.18
```

And your roommate owes

```
737.50 + 69.68 + 91 = 898.18
```